# Using ellipsize with two textView horizontally without crop the second one

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have a two textView on the same line. Below you can see what is the interaction when my `String` object is long and when is short.

I'm trying to do this in android xml view.

**(Second text have to stay on the right of the first one when the first one is short)**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingRight="40dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:text="TextView long"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Text"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="15sp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

My problem here is that my second text "Text" stay on the right parent each time...

Comment: Why you set android:layout_width="0dp"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use tablelayout and put both textbox in table row have a try.Check this code.

```
  <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textview"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:singleLine="true"
            />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use weight in first TextView. Check this code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="TextView toooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo long"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Simple Text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would like to keep the second textView on the right of the first one when the first textView string is short.

Comment: I can see thanks. But now my second textView disappear if the first textView is too long... :/ That's my problem.